# Trying to get the minute interval at :00 and :30

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-workspace

In my code that was customized, I have not added any time sequence to be add, and in the trigger I even made a minute interval for every 30 minutes and made sure to submit the interval at 00:00 AM at the dot. However I am getting updates and response at :24 and :54, you can check the screenshot I posted.

Screenshot of the 30-minute time sequence[image]

Not sure why it is doing that, if anyone knows that will be amazing. Also for my timezone, I have placed under **(GMT-4:00) Eastern Time - Toronto**. I am not sure if timezone has any affect in this, but if anyone knows that will be amazing.

Thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Not that timed events may be somewhat randomized.  See this [article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: AFAIK they try to give you your trigger close to where you ask but not necessarily exactly where you ask.  Sorry but that's the nature of a share system.